# Why does this task config not allow me to compile multiple C++ files in VS Code on Windows?

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-code, task, forward-declaration

So I have looked at some other Stack Overflow questions, and tried a few things to my task file in VS Code to compile multiple C++ files. However, it isn't seeming to work and am a bit confused why it is still not linking. I'd prefer to use VS Code and not an IDE, so I really want to get this working.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int add(int x, int y);

int main(){
    std::cout << add(1, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

test.cpp

```
int add(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "g++.exe build",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

My folders are as follows:

[Folder Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfpRr.png)

Any help would be amazing as I can't seem to get this even after reading other posts about this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe your tasks.json is not being used because you have code-runner enabled.

Comment: tasks.json is supposed to be in the `.vscode` folder and not supposed to be in the same folder as your cpp files.

Comment: @drescherjm That does seem to be the issue. Why would code runner be causing this? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is something wrong with input file path pattern `${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp`:

```json
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp", // Would you like to change it to ${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
```

PS:
would you like to put the `tasks.json` into `.vscode` folder

Comment: I tried it this way as well and it did not work. Same issue.

Answer (score -4):

In my opinion,the test.cpp was not been includeed by main.cpp.
#include "test.cpp"

Comment: Including .cpp files is not the best idea. They should be compiled separately and linked together.